# I'm trying to determine the domain and range of user input ordered pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I have the users input in a vector of pairs. I am trying to determine the domain by just removing the duplicate x values. Then I need to determine the range by  all the unique values of y. I have looked into map. I cant seem to figure it out. This is homework so I would prefer to understand how to do it rather than just a solution. Thanks!

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<pair<int, int> > sample;
vector< vector<int> > relation;
vector< vector<int> > domain;
vector< vector<int> > range;
bool loop = true;

do {
    int input;
    int input2;
    cout << "Enter the first INT in the ordered pair: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "Enter the second INT in the ordered pair: ";
    cin >> input2;
    if (input != -1 && input2 != -1) {
        sample.push_back(make_pair(input, input2));
    }
    else if (input != -1 && input2 == -1) {
        cout << "ERROR,  must input 2 INTS for an ordered pair." << endl;
        loop = false;
    }
    else if (input == -1) {
        loop = false;
    }
} while (loop == true);

map<int, int> s;
int size = sample.size();
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) s.insert(sample[i]);
sample.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
cout << "TEST: { ";
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    cout << "(" << s[i].first << "," << s[i].second << ")" << ", ";
}
cout << "}" << endl;

cout << "Relation: { ";
for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
    cout << "(" << sample[i].first << "," << sample[i].second << ")" << ", ";
}
cout << "}" << endl;

cout << "Domain: { ";
for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
    cout << sample[i].first << ", ";
}
cout << "}" << endl;

cout << "Range: { ";
for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
    cout << sample[i].second << ", ";
}
cout << "}" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, instead of inputing the pairs into a vector, and then copying the vector in the map, you can just input the pairs directly into the map. Also, since the map stores keys in order, you can immediately determine the domain by the first and the last key in the map. Then copy the values from the map into a set, and determine the range by looking at the first and the last value in the set, since a set also orders its values in order.

Comment: Would putting the pairs directly into the map still allow the user to input duplicates? Do you have an example of how to copy the values from a map into a set?

Comment: There's nothing that a map can do to prevent you from accepting user input. As far as copying the values from map into a set, it's differs very little from copying values from a vector into a map. Same approach: iterate over one container, copy the value into a different container. You already shown that you know how to do that.

Comment: I dont think map is going to work. Map is deleting all keys that are not unique. For instance, when i enter 1,5 1,6, 1,4 my program only prints the first 1,5. I'm not sure if its something i'm doing or if its just a feature of map

Comment: That's what a map is supposed to do, and you get this result whether you first enter the input into a vector and copy it to the map, or enter it directly into the map in the first place. An attempt to insert an existing key into the map fails. That's a fundamental property of a map. That was the obvious reason you used it in the original version of your code, by first copying the data into a map, then back into a vector. There was no other reason for you to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the unique values of `x` and `y` (without worrying about the relationships between them), you should just be able to use a couple of sets (`std::set`).

Just create two empty sets, `xset` and `yset` then run through all the coordinates in your original vector.

For each coordinate, add the `x` value to `xset` and the `y` value to `yset`.

Then, when you're done, you have all the unique values in both sets and you can extract the smallest and largest (or all values) from each to give range and domain.

The following code (don't use this verbatim in assignments, you'll almost certainly be pinged for plagiarism) shows how this can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef pair < int, int > tPII;
typedef vector < tPII > tVPII;
typedef vector < int > tVI;
typedef set < int > tSI;

int main() {
    // Test data to use.

    tVPII sample;
    tPII a (     1,      2); sample.push_back (a);
    tPII b (     9,     99); sample.push_back (b);
    tPII c (314158, 271828); sample.push_back (c);
    tPII d (     1,     77); sample.push_back (d);
    tPII e (     1,     99); sample.push_back (e);

    // Place individual coordinates into sets.

    cout << "input data:\n";
    tSI xset, yset;
    for (tVPII::iterator it = sample.begin(); it != sample.end(); ++it) {
        cout << "   (" << it->first << "," << it->second << ")\n";
        xset.insert (it->first);
        yset.insert (it->second);
    }

    // Construct range/domain vectors from sets.

    tVI xvals;
    tVI yvals;
    for (tSI::iterator it = xset.begin(); it != xset.end(); ++it)
        xvals.push_back (*it);
    for (tSI::iterator it = yset.begin(); it != yset.end(); ++it)
        yvals.push_back (*it);

    // Output range/domain vectors.

    cout << "x values:\n";
    for (tVI::iterator it = xvals.begin(); it != xvals.end(); ++it)
        cout << "   " << *it << "\n";
    cout << "y values:\n";
    for (tVI::iterator it = yvals.begin(); it != yvals.end(); ++it)
        cout << "   " << *it << "\n";
}
```

The output of that shows how the information flows into the set (removing duplicates) and back out into individual vectors for the `x` and `y` values:

```
input data:
   (1,2)
   (9,99)
   (314158,271828)
   (1,77)
   (1,99)
x values:
   1
   9
   314158
y values:
   2
   77
   99
   271828
```

Keep in mind that this treats `x` and `y` values as totally separate. *If* you don't want to take into the account the `y` values for coordinates where `x` already exists, it's a slight modification:

```
// Place individual coordinates into sets,
// discount coordinates totally if x has already been seen.

cout << "input data:\n";
tSI xset, yset;
for (tVPII::iterator it = sample.begin(); it != sample.end(); ++it) {
    cout << "   (" << it->first << "," << it->second << ") - ";
    if (xset.find (it->first) != xset.end()) {
        cout << "duplicate.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "inserting.\n";
        xset.insert (it->first);
        yset.insert (it->second);
    }
}
```

The output of *that* shows the changed behaviour:

```
input data:
   (1,2) - inserting.
   (9,99) - inserting.
   (314158,271828) - inserting.
   (1,77) - duplicate.
   (1,99) - duplicate.
x values:
   1
   9
   314158
y values:
   2
   99
   271828
```

Comment: The OP appears to want to first eliminate all records with duplicate x values, then determine the range of the y values, so this is slightly more work.

Comment: I understand that a set automatically eliminates duplicates, so would I just copy the first element of each pair into a set? What would that syntax look like?

Comment: I wont copy it, I'd rather understand it. So the typedef's at top setup basically templates? (sorry I am unfamiliar with typedef) So you're setting up a vector, and passing pairs into the vector? And because it's a set, it only allows unique values?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, have provided a slight modification which takes that into account.

Comment: @phillis, the typedefs are just because I hate typing template stuff :-) You could just as easily use (for example) `pair < int, int >` wherever I currently have `tPII`. And you're basically right. Taking each "thing" from a vector (which allows duplicates) and placing them all into a set, automatically removes the duplicates.

Comment: @paxdiablo, thank you for your response. I looked into typedef a little and now feel as if i understand your code. Thanks for explaining and showing an example!